# Students grade average

Tags: c

I have to calculate the average grade of each student at each subject. The grades, students and subjects are read from a file. The structs are dynamically allocated.
The files look like this:

students.txt

```
2, student1  
7, student2  
1, student3
```

subject.txt

```
5, math  
3, physics  
8, geography
```

grades.txt

date, number of grades
student code, subject code, grade

```
18.06.2020, 3  
2, 3, 10  
1, 8, 7  
7, 5, 9  
19.06.2020, 2  
8, 3, 8  
3, 8, 6
```

In 18.06.2020 the student with code 2 got 10 at the subject with code 3.

I stored these values in structs:

```
#define N 20
struct Subject {
    char subjectName[N];
    int code;
};
struct Students {
    char studentName[N];
    int code;
};
struct Grades {
    int grade[N][3];
    char date[N];
    int number_of_grades;   // number of grades in a day
};
struct Date {
    int number_of_days;     // total number of days
    int number_of_students; // total number of students
    int number_of_subjects; // total number of  subjects
}data;
```

These are the function I used to read the values from the files. Functions I used for other things.

```
void filechack(FILE* f){
    if (f == NULL) {
        printf("The file cannot be opened");
        exit(1);
    }
}

struct Subject* subject() {
    struct Subject *ptr;
    int i;
    FILE *f = fopen("subject.txt", "r");
    filechack(f);
    ptr = NULL;
    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++){
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(struct Subject)*(i+1));
        if (ptr == NULL){
            printf("Meomry not allocated");
            exit(1);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%d, %19s\n", &(ptr+i)->code, (ptr+i)->subjectName);
    }
    fclose(f);
    data.number_of_subjects = i;
    return ptr;
}

struct Students* students(){
    struct Students* ptr = NULL;
    int i;
    FILE *f = fopen("students.txt", "r");
    filechack(f);
    for (i = 0; !feof(f); i++){
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(struct Students)*(i+1));
        if (ptr == NULL){
            printf("Meomry not allocated");
            exit(1);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%d, %[^\n]", &(ptr+i)->code, (ptr+i)->studentName);
    }
    data.number_of_students = i;
    fclose(f);
    return ptr;
}

struct Grades* grades(){
    struct Grades* ptr = NULL;
    int i, j;
    FILE* f = fopen("grades.txt", "r");
    filechack(f);
    for(i = 0; !feof(f); i++){
        ptr = realloc(ptr, sizeof(struct Grades)*(i+1));
        if (ptr == NULL){
            printf("Meomry not allocated");
            exit(1);
        }
        fscanf(f, "%[^,], %d\n", (ptr+i)->date, &(ptr+i)->number_of_grades);
        for(j = 0; j<(ptr+i)->number_of_grades; j++){
            fscanf(f, "%d, %d, %d\n", &(ptr+i)->grade[j][0], &(ptr+i)->grade[j][1], &(ptr+i)->grade[j][2]);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    data.number_of_days = i;
    return ptr;
}
```

Now I don't know how can I find the grades average for each students at each subject. I think the best way would be to store the average in the Students struct and than print it to the screen. The problem is that I don't know how to do it. Maybe you can give me an advice or a tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be helpful to store the grades based on the student they belong to. You could add a field to the Student struct to hold it's grades, like

```
struct Student {
    char studentName[N];
    int code;
    int *grades;
    int no_grades;
}
```

Each time you read in a grade from file, you could search through the students and add the grade under the relevant student. That way, when you finish reading in you will have the access to each student's grades, and it would be much easier to calculate the average.

Hope this helps!